# DateTimePicker inline no funciona - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Necesito visualizar el calendario en forma `inline`, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught Error: Could not initialize DateTimePicker without an input element

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No estas utilizando tambien jquery datepicker verdad?

Comment: bueno la verdad, veo que tengo jquery.timepicker, tiene eso que ver en el error ?

Comment: si es el timepicker no hay problema. Si es un datetimepicker si.

Comment: solo tengo bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js y los css del datetimepicker no se que pasa que me esta dando ese error

Comment: Verifica mi respuesta y dime si te funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos exactamente qué datepicker estás usando? Proporciona al menos los enlaces de script y CSS para poder ayudarte mejor. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En base lo que dices, tienes que verificar que tengas la libreria actualizada. Aqui el ejemplo funcionado con todas sus las dependencias:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
      
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

¿Seguro que tienes la [ultima version del datetimepicker](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js)?

Comment: estuve viendo eso, pero realmente lo que me hace falta es que me salga como en la imagen sin input solo como esta en la imagen

Comment: Ok, ya entendi. Actualize mi respuesta. Date una mirada. Probablemente tienes una version no actualizada.

Comment: exactamente eso es lo que quiero voy a probar

Comment: tenia una version de datetimepicker 4.0.0 voy a probar eso y te comento